# equation transformation for y=√x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with this problem not sure if it's correct

I have y=√x
It says shifts up 6
Reflects on the y axis 
Then shifted right 4 units

I ended up getting y=-√x-4+6

If this not correct please school me on what I did incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: I'd "school you", but your notation is ambiguous...

Comment: To write $y = \sqrt{x}$, write y = \sqrt{x} between dollar signs.  If you meant $y = -\sqrt{x - 4} + 6$, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Shift up: $\sqrt x+6$
Reflect: $-\sqrt x -6$
Shift right: $-\sqrt{x-4}-6$